# Capitalize part name in amsbook

Tags: table-of-contents, babel, parts, amsbook, babel-french

In French, the `amsbook` class writes part name in lowercase in the toc even if I redefine `\partname`. I wonder how to fix that.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\title{La démocratie}
\author{Quelqu'un}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents
  \mainmatter
  \part{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to keep “Première partie” in the title, so here are a couple of hacks.

First, the code in `babel-french` doesn't consider that `\thepart` is preceded by a space that should be ignored (or removed), so I fix it by (locally) redefining `\thepart` to `\unskip` instead of doing nothing.

Second, I patch `\@part` to make it write directly `Partie` instead of `\partname` in the `toc` file.

```latex
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% fix a small issue in babel-french
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\FB@emptypart{\def\thepart{\unskip}}
% make \part write 'Partie' instead of '\partname'
\patchcmd{\@part}{\partname}{Partie}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{La démocratie}
\author{Quelqu'un}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\part{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the `babel-french` [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/french/frenchb.pdf) `PartNameFull` should be set to `false` to avoid such problems.

So just add `\frenchsetup{PartNameFull=false}` to your preamble. This should solve your issue.

Extract of the documentation:

> PartNameFull=false (true);
>
> when true, babel-french numbers the title
> of \part{} commands as “Première partie”, “Deuxième partie” and so
> on. With some classes which change the \part{} command (AMS classes
> do so), you could get “Première partie 1”, “Deuxième partie 2” in the
> toc; when this occurs, this option should be set to false, part titles
> will then be printed as “Partie I”, “Partie II”.