# Capitalize French part name

Tags: babel, titlesec, parts, babel-french

It is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519642/capitalize-part-name-in-amsbook/), but both of its answer do not seem to work here.

I defined the title format as follows:

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{top} % make part like a chapter
\titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\raggedleft}
    {\MakeUppercase{\partname}~\thepart}
    {1em}
    {\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
```

Thus, ideally, one should see `PARTIE I` in a new part. But actually one would see `Première partie I`.

The method in the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519655/194994) does not have effect to this. On the other hand, with the following babel setting,

```
\frenchsetup{PartNameFull=false}
```

The result would become `Partie I`, still not in uppercase.

How can I fix this behavior? Or is there some way to just show `Première partie` without the `I` in French mode?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{top} % make part like a chapter
\titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\raggedleft}
    {\MakeUppercase{\partname}~\thepart}
    {1em}
    {\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

%% This produces "Partie"
% \frenchsetup{PartNameFull=false}%

%% These seem to have no effect
% \usepackage{etoolbox}
% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand\FB@emptypart{\def\thepart{\unskip}}
% \patchcmd{\@part}{\partname}{Partie}{}{}
% \makeatother

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}
\part{Test}

\selectlanguage{english}
\part{Test}

\end{document}
```

**ADD:** I should mention that `polyglossia` doesn't have this problem, but on the other hand, one cannot get things like `Première partie` by its newly offered option `frenchpart=true` without any effort --- a "patch failure" is reported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The french babel support tries to ensue that constructs like `\partname~\thepart` automatically get translated into "Première partie" by (locally) changing `\thepart` to suppress the number. This fails in your example because the `\MakeUppercase` make the local redefinition end before `\thepart` gets invoked. This can be avoided by moving `\thepart` into it's argument and protecting it:

Change `{\MakeUppercase{\partname}~\thepart}` to `{\MakeUppercase{\partname~\protect\thepart}}` to get "Première partie".

You can also locally redefine `\frenchpartname` to ensure that it works with `\MakeUppercase`:

Change

```
{\MakeUppercase{\partname}~\thepart}
```

to

```
{\renewcommand\frenchpartname{Partie}\MakeUppercase{\partname}~\thepart}
```

to get "PARTIE I".

Answer (score 6):

The command `\partname` is defined to do complicated things that in your case are not needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\part}{top} % make part like a chapter
\titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\filleft}
    {\MakeUppercase{\partname}~\thepart}
    {1em}
    {\MakeUppercase}
\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand{\partname}{Partie}}

\begin{document}

%\selectlanguage{french} % French is already default
\part{Test}

\selectlanguage{english}
\part{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A couple of notes: `titlesec` prefers `\filleft` to `\raggedleft`. There's no need to use `explicit`: the last token in the final mandatory argument to `\titleformat` is eventually followed by the braced title, so it can be a one-argument macro.

Actually, I usually discourage using `explicit`: better defining a separate macro that does what we want rather than clutter the argument to `\titleformat` with code.

Comment: In fact, the use of option `explicit` is because of my wish to separately define the numberless case, so that the part title is on the same vertical position comparing with the ones with numbers. Do you think there's a better way to achieve this?

Comment: @Jinwen Nothing prevents you to use different macros in the final argument to `\titleformat` for the numbered and the numberless versions.